# Execute mysql query in php in loop with parameters stored in arrayList coming from android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I have an ArrayList() in my android app containing names of books. I am using android Volley library for server requests. I want to add all these books in my BookList(table) in my database which is in the server. I want to do it using a single server request i.e. using a single php file. How can this php code be written such that it inserts all these values in the table using loop? Some Codes will be really helpful

Comment: convert the arraylist into json string, and send it to the server. PHP will then json_decode the json, loop, and just run the insert query for each row.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507749/send-arraylist-from-android-to-php-mysql) ,this might help you !

Comment: @Afif Zafri Can you please post some example code about how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with the help from the comments.
Firstly, I created JSONArrays from the arrayLists. Then I posted them to php via android volley.

private Map params;

```
    JSONArray bookNamesJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(bookNames));
    JSONArray bookAuthorsJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(bookAuthors));
    JSONArray subjectsJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(subjects));


    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("candidateId", id + "");
    params.put("bookName",bookNamesJSON.toString());
    params.put("authorName",bookAuthorsJSON.toString());
    params.put("subjectName",subjectsJSON.toString());
    params.put("reqDate",date);
```

Then in php I had to do this:

```
$candidateId=$_POST["candidateId"];
$reqDate=$_POST["reqDate"];
$subjectName = json_decode($_POST["subjectName"])[0];
$bookName = json_decode($_POST["bookName"])[0];
$authorName = json_decode($_POST["authorName"])[0];


$response = array();
foreach ($subjectName as $i => $subject) 
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO BookRequisition VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);");
    $stmt->bind_param("dssss", $candidateId, $subject, $bookName[$i], $authorName[$i], $reqDate);
    $stmt->execute();
}


$response["success"] = true;



echo json_encode($response);
```

Hope this helps someone.